# Cannot assign to 'd' because it is not a variable typescript

Tags: typescript, variables, import, interface

Hi I am having two files that use the same interface and variable so I am trying to import the variable to another typescript file. The interface is imported too from a global interface file.

```
declare interface personInterface {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
}

export let d: personInterface = {
    name: '',
    surname: ''
};
```

I am importing then d in another file:

```
import { d } from "./file";

d = sessionStorage.getItem("person");
```

I get the following error:
Cannot assign to 'd' because it is not a variable.

Comment: @ShamPooSham would like to know your opinion if you can help :)

Comment: you cannot reassign imported values, they are not variables, but constants

Comment: Tank you both! Makes sense

Answer (score 1):

`import {d} from ...` works like

```
const d = ...;
```

that is why you cannot reassign a constant